# How to float elements inside a container

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to put the `#container` in the center of the screen and make the 'charts' `float:left` inside the `#container`.

But with the code I have below, the 'charts' locate under the `#container`. Can anyone tell me how can I change the code? And tell me why the code make the 'charts' outside the `#container`.

```css
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 10%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
#id1,
#id2,
#id3,
#id4 {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="id1">
    <p>chart1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="id2">
    <p>chart2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="id3">
    <p>chart3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="id4">
    <p>chart4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want `charts` to be inline

Comment: I want to have two 'charts' in a line. When the third chart comes, it switches to a new line automatically. Thanks

Comment: And you want `container` fixed `width: 10%;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add float to an element you're taking out of the natural flow of the document.

You will need to add some sort of clearfix to the wrapper of the floated items.

```css
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

#container{
    margin: auto;
    width: 10%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    padding: 10px;
}
#id1,
#id2,
#id3,
#id4 {
    float:left;
    font-size: 30px;    
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div id="id1"><p>chart1</p></div>
  <div id="id2"><p>chart2</p></div>
  <div id="id3"><p>chart3</p></div>
  <div id="id4"><p>chart4</p></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If the width is fixed why would you float the divs?

Answer (score 1):

whenever you `float` you need to clear the `float` items, plus use classes instead of ID's if you are applying the same attributes.
Increase the `width` for your container in order to have 2 items per row as stated in your comment above

```css
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.cf:after {
  clear: both;
}
#container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 24%; /* to have 2 divs per row */
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
}
.float {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="cf">
  <div class="float">
    <p>chart1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="float">
    <p>chart2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="float">
    <p>chart3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="float">
    <p>chart4</p>
  </div>
</div>
```